# How to do one to one mapping hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables:
A

Having columns

1.type(pk)
2.description

B

Having columns

1.id (pk)
2.type(fk)
3.more info

now i want to achieve one to one mapping between two,But unable to achieve it.Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate, a one to one mapping could be defined in the owning side of the relation (java model class) with these java annotations:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "column_name")
private type attributeName;
```

In particular:

- `@OneToOne` indicates to Hibernate the type of the relation;
- `@JoinColumn` indicates the name of the column in the database that will hold the reference to the linked entity.

in case you want to define a bidirectional relation, you have to map it on the other side with the annotation `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "column_name")` on the related entity.

For further examples https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one